# Need a Backend Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction

I have created a compiler that produces an intermediate code. I do not have the time to write the backend for my project.

**Is there any software I could use to evaluate the intermediate code produced? Where could I download this software?**

The output looks something like this :

```
    t1 = 0.67596e-7
    sum = t1

    t1 = 2
    t2 = 3
    t3 = t2 + t1
    i = t3

L0:
    t1 = sum
    t2 = 20
t3 = compare(t1 <= t2)
    t4 = sum
    t5 = 12
t6 = compare(t4 ~= t5)
t7 = t3 | t6
    t8 = sum
    t9 = 20
t10 = compare(t8 > t9)
t11 = t7 & t10
if t11 true then goto L1 else goto L2
L1: 
    t1 = 2
    t2 = sum
    t3 = t2 + t1
    sum = t3

    t1 = 1
    t2 = i
    t3 = t2 + t1
    i = t3
    goto L0
L2:
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446883/best-compiler-destination/

Answer (score 15):

Code generation is my business :-)

Comments on a few options:

- CLR:

  - Pro: industrial support
  - Con: you have to buy into their type system pretty much completely; depending on what you want to do with types, this may not matter
  - Con: Only Windows platform is really prime-time quality
- LLVM:

  - Pro: enthusiastic user community with charismatic leader
  - Pro: many interesting performance improvements
  - Con: somewhat complex interface
  - Con: history of holes in the engineering; as LLVM matures expect the holes in the engineering to be plugged by adding to the complexity of the interface
- [C--](http://www.cminusminus.org/)

  - Pro: target is an actual written language, not an API; you can easily inspect, debug, and edit your C-- code
  - Pro: design is reasonably mature and reasonably clean
  - Pro: supports accurate garbage collection
  - Pro: most users report it is very easy to use
  - Con: very small development team
  - Con: as of early 2009, supports only three hardware platforms (x86, PPC, ARM)
  - Con: does not ship with a garbage collector
  - Con: future of project is uncertain
- C as target language

  - Pro: looks easy
  - Con: nearly impossible to get decent performance
  - Con: will drive you nuts in the long run; ask the long line of people who have tried to compile Haskell, ML, Modula-3, Scheme and more using this technique.  At some point every one of these people gave up and built their own native code generator.

Summary: **anything except C** is a reasonable choice.  For the best combination of flexibility, quality, and expected longevity, I'd probably recommend LLVM.  But your example code is very close to C--, so that may be an advantage.

Full disclosure: I am affiliated with the C-- project.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I want to know what you mean by "nearly impossible to get decent performance".

Comment: @KiedLlaentenn there are long papers on that topic, for example, see section 3 of https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/c--/download/pal-ifl.ps.gz

Comment: vlang and nim are really good examples of languages that transpile to C

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the [llvm compiler infrastructure project](http://llvm.org/). It is used in a lot of real world projects. The LLVM is a low level virtual machine, easy to create code for and easy to translate to native code.

Answer (score 8):

Your emitted code looks pretty close to C - whay not have your compiler emit C and use a C compiler as the backend - that's the way the original C++ cfront compiler worked.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend spitting out Pascal code and using [Free pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/).

It's natively compiled, compilation is blazing fast and you can target a plethora of platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Why not target another high level language as the intermediate output, for example you could generate C code, and use any C compiler to compile that.  This has been used by a number of high level languages in the past.

Another slightly lower level option would be to generate IL code and use the .NET runtime.  If the compiler is written in .NET you can use the Reflection.Emit namespace to generate a  .NET assembly which can then be run in any .NET environment.

Answer (score 2):

You may have better luck selecting a compiler stack and using the intermediate code supported by that stack. For example, gcc uses [RTL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html), register transfer language as a common denominator for all languages supported by gcc. I suspect that .net has something similar that's used for things like IronPython.

If you want to use something that supplies a virtual machine for evaluating code, the [SPIM MIPS](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html) vm supports the Motorola 68000 architecture and is really easy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative nobody has mentioned is [QBE](https://c9x.me/compile/).

> QBE aims to be a pure C embeddable backend that provides 70% of the performance of advanced compilers in 10% of the code.

It is like LLVM, but it's a lot lighter as a dependency. From [the comparison to LLVM](https://c9x.me/compile/doc/llvm.html):

> QBE is for amateur language designers.
>
> It does not address all the problems faced when conceiving an industry-grade language. If you are toying with some language ideas, using LLVM will be like hauling your backpack with a truck, but using QBE will feel more like riding a bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

[NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/specs) is designed to accept a high level IL similar to yours and then run it. Neil Butterworth's suggestion to use C is also a good choice.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken, https://nekovm.org still works though

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a dependency on the JVM, then it is pretty simple to generate byte-code using [ASM](http://asm.objectweb.org/).

If you can't, then [gnu lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) can be used for on-the-fly code generation (smaller and simpler than LLVM, but without the optimisations).

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is `C`-ish, you could try [`C--`](http://www.cminusminus.org/).  It a `C` like language for compiler backends.  IIRC, it's used by one of the major Haskell compilers.

Answer (score 0):

highly recommend llvm, a platform-cross infrastructure, support machine-code generation and many passes of optimization. The tutorial on llvm.org is very simple.