# Generating Rust executable from LLVM bitcode

Tags: rust, llvm-ir, bitcode

How can I generate an executable of an application written in Rust that was compiled into LLVM-IR bitcode?

If I try to compile the .bc file with rustc it tells me `stream did not contain valid UTF-8` and I can't seem to figure out if there is a specific option in rustc for this.

Basically I want to achieve this:
`program.rs` -> `program.bc` -> `program`.
Where `program` is the final executable. What steps should I make to achieve this?

Comment: `rustc` is the Rust compiler, it doesn't compile other input formats. Why not use LLVM's `llc` or equivalent if you have the bitcode?

Comment: That was my initial guess but I'm not very familiar with llc and only found this: -filetype                                                      - Choose a file type (not all types are supported by all targets):
    =asm                                                         -   Emit an assembly ('.s') file
    =obj                                                         -   Emit a native object ('.o') file
    =null                                                        -   Emit nothing, for performance testing. None of them seemed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with this source code:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

You can create LLVM *intermediate representation* (IR) or *bitcode* (BC):

```sh
# IR in hello.ll
rustc hello.rs --emit=llvm-ir
# BC in hello.bc
rustc hello.rs --emit=llvm-bc
```

These files can then be further processed by LLVM to produce *assembly* or an *object file*:

```sh
# Assembly in hello.s
llc hello.bc
# Object in hello.o
llc hello.bc --filetype=obj
```

Then you need to link the files to produce an executable. This requires linking to the Rust standard libraries. The path is platform- and version-dependent:

```sh
cc -L/path/to/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/ -lstd-f4a73f2c70e583e1 -o hello2 hello.o
```

You can then run the program:

```sh
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/ ./hello2
```

This answer has macOS specific solutions, but the general concepts *should* be extendable to Linux and Windows. The implementation will differ slightly for Linux and probably greatly for Windows. Notably, I'm using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as I've dynamically linked to the Rust standard library which isn't in my usual library search path.

Note that LLVM IR and BC files don't have the strongest forward / backward compatibility guarantees. This means that you need to use a version of `llc` that is compatible with the version of `rustc` you are using. For this answer, I used an `llc` that was produced by my local Rust development build:

```
% rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.53.0 (53cb7b09b 2021-06-17)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 53cb7b09b00cbea8754ffb78e7e3cb521cb8af4b
commit-date: 2021-06-17
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.53.0
LLVM version: 12.0.1

% llc --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 12.0.1-rust-dev
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
  Host CPU: skylake
```

See also:

- [How stable is the LLVM assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15836430/155423)

Comment: What is the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/stage2/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/ for?

Comment: @LeonardoMarques When I linked the object files with the standard library, it used dynamic linking. Since the Rust standard library isn't in my default library search path, I have to inform the dynamic linker where to find it at program execution time. You could build a static binary instead (which is a bit tricky for me on OS X, so I skipped it) or if the standard library was in the search path the runtime linker would know where to find it.

Comment: isn't -lstd-2f39a9bd suposed to have a .dylib extension? Why is it tricky to build a static binary?

Comment: @LeonardoMarques that's just how the `-l` flag works. It prepends a `lib` and adds `.dylib` (or `.so`, or whatever is appropriate for the platform).

Comment: Why is it tricky to build a static binary? (I'm also working on MacOSX)

Comment: @LeonardoMarques ["Apple does not support statically linked binaries on Mac OS X"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html). Also see [Creating static Mac OS X C build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5259249/155423). Stack Overflow has lots of these details fleshed out. :-)

Comment: @Shepmaster I get an error when I try to replicate your commands (`llc hello.bc`).
```llc: error: llc: hello.bc: error: Unknown attribute kind (61) (Producer: 'LLVM11.0.0-rust-1.49.0-stable' Reader: 'LLVM 7.1.0')```

Comment: @rambi as the error message states, LLVM 7.1.0 cannot read data from LLVM 11.0.0. You will need to match the versions.

Comment: thanks ! I saw this helpfull post to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836430/how-stable-is-the-llvm-assembly-language

Answer (score 5):

It isn't obvious since the LLVM documentation is very obscure, but *clang* will compile both LLVM IR files (".ll") and bitcode files (".bc"), and link with your system libraries.

On Linux with Rust 1.9:

```
clang -dynamic-linker /usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-d16b8f0e.so  hello.ll -o hello
```